# Why does Qt complain about invalid XML version in ui file

Tags: xml, qt, qt-designer, pyside6, uic

I'm trying to port an application from PyQt5 to PySide6 because it's the official bindings (for now I guess). I have a .ui file designed in Qt Designer. It loads fine using PyQt5 uic, but PySide6 gives me the following error:

```
Designer: An error has occurred while reading the UI file at line 1, column 38: Unsupported XML version.
```

The first line of that file says:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I've tried loading the file dynamically and I've tried to compile the .ui file using pyside6-uic. I get the same error each time.

Why can't PySide6 read my ui file?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such xml version as 2.0 - the only [specified versions](https://www.w3.org/XML/Core/) are 1.0 and 1.1. Qt will currently refuse to load ui files that aren't xml version 1.0, so I don't know how you ended up with anything different. Anyway, just manually change the version to 1.0, and everything should work as expected.

PS: as a nice irony, the so-called "unofficial" PyQt tools will handle any xml version, valid or otherwise (-;